# Python 3 - Assert a boolean.

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

I have overridden `__eq___` in a class that I'm currently doctesting. All the methods (not showed) work fine, but when I added `__eq__`, I get an error message.

My method:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    """ Tests if two dual objects are equal or not. 

    Returns
    ------- 
    True or false, depending on the comparison

    Examples
    -------- 
    >>> z = Dual(1, 1)
    >>> y = Dual(1, 1)
    >>> z == y
    True
    """
    # compare the real and dual parts of self versus other.
    #Output True if both cases match, false otherwise. 
    if self.r == other.r and self.d == other.d:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

In my doctesting file, the following method is meant to test that this method works:

```
def test_eq():
    z = sj.Dual(1,1)
    y = sj.Dual(1,1)
    assert z == y
```

The error message I get is as follows:

```
=================================== FAILURES ===================================
___________________________________ test_eq ____________________________________
    def test_eq():
        z = sj.Dual(1,1)
        y = sj.Dual(1,1)
>       assert z == y
E       assert 1.00 + eps 1.00 == 1.00 + eps 1.00
spacejam/tests/dualnumbers_test.py:53: AssertionError
=============================== warnings summary ===============================
/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/src/spacejam/spacejam/dual.py:23
  /home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/src/spacejam/spacejam/dual.py:23: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \p
    """
```

Is there something I am doing terrifically wrong or overlooking?

Comment: error is clearly showing that value of z and y are in form "1.00 + eps 1.00" which you can not directly compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is clearly showing that value of z and y are in form "1.00 + eps 1.00" which you can not directly compare.
you can do below :

```
assert z.r == y.r
assert z.d == z.d
```